# If API Data Fails to Load then do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, geolocation

I am using a geo lookup API called [wipmania](https://www.wipmania.com/) to find out what country a user is from and perform a few different types of things.

```
jQuery.getJSON('https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) { 
 // Do my code based on result here. 
});
```

I just found out this API is now failing so my site is not executing the code and I need some sort of fall back.

I am not sure as I can't reach their site if it is documented how I can say if data is not returned after 2 seconds then do something else.

Does anyone know of a way I can have a fall back for the API not returning anything. It basically just waits on it forever to return. Guess in Puesdo terms looking for something like

```
if API call returns data {
 // execute code per country
} else {
 // do other code as fallback we can't detect country
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fail() callback to handle an unsuccessful result of jQuery.getJSON(). For example:

```
jQuery.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
    console.log( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log( "Failed to get JSON" );
});
```

Comment: thank you did not know about the .fail..now I do! Thanks a lot

Comment: quick question would the function need to include `data` on each `function()` ? For example `.fail(function(data)` per my example?

Comment: getJSON() is just a shorthand equivalent to the jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) method. If you need that kind of information, you can see what the api is returning (as well as have access to a much wider api) [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/mDCN7/)